# Return window in hitTest does not work

Tags: ios, uiwindow

I am trying to add custom UIWindow and forward the event to the mainWindow

```
-(UIView *) hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
UIView *hitView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
if (hitView == self.myView) {
    return hitView;
}else{
    return mainWindow;
}}
```

It works when passing the View inside mainWindow.rootViewController.view
but I want to pass it to the mainWindow

Comment: Why are you doing that then?

Comment: @trojanfoe I would like to add popover window over status bar and I would like to pass any touch outside the bounders of the popOver to mainWindow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for my question is returning nil 
it will pass it to next hosted window

```
-(UIView *) hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
  UIView *hitView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    if (hitView == self.myView) {
        return hitView;
       }else{
         return nil;
      }}
```